# Как реализовать валидацию INotifyDataErrorInfo для отдельного свойства объекта модели

Tags: c#, wpf, валидация

Есть некий объект бизнес модели `Participant` который имеет множество текстовых свойств, содержащих полное и краткое имя субъекта, каждое в 6 падежах, итого 12 свойств:

```
public class Participant 
{
//...
    public string NameShort1 {get; set;}
    public string NameShort2 {get; set;}
    public string NameShort3 {get; set;}
    public string NameShort4 {get; set;}
    public string NameShort5 {get; set;}
    public string NameShort6 {get; set;}


    public string NameLong1 {get; set;}
    public string NameLong2 {get; set;}
    public string NameLong3 {get; set;}
    public string NameLong4 {get; set;}
    public string NameLong5 {get; set;}
    public string NameLong6 {get; set;}
//...
}
```

Очевидно, что в моей модели представления, которая реализована через `INotifyPropertyChanged` я привязываю экземпляр данного объекта целиком, а не как набор из 12+ свойств привязки, чтобы не захламлять код, примерно так:

```
    private Participant selectedParticipant;
    public Participant SelectedParticipant
    {
        get { return selectedParticipant; }
        set
        {
            selectedParticipant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParticipant");
        }
    }
```

Соответствующее представление имеет стопку текстбоксов для редактирования текстовых полей:

```
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="И:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong1}"  />
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="Р:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong2}" />
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="Д:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong3}" />
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="В:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong4}" />
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="Т:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong5}" />
                    <local:CustomTextbox LabelText="П:" Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong6}" />
                </StackPanel>
```

Проблема возникает, когда я пытаюсь использовать INotifyDataErrorInfo на свойствах объекта `SelectedClient` не меняя конфигурацию привязки. Ниже приведена моя попытка реализовать валидацию свойства `NameLong1`:

```
    private Participant selectedParticipant;
    public Participant SelectedParticipant
    {
        get { return selectedParticipant; }
        set
        {
            //Удаляю ранее созданные ошибки
            dataErrorVM.ClearErrors("SelectedParticipant.NameLong1");
            //Проверяю NameLong1 на длину строки - не более 10 символов
            if (value.NameLong1.Length > 10)
                dataErrorVM.AddError("SelectedParticipant.NameLong1", "name is too long");
            selectedParticipant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParticipant");
        }
    }
```

Изменение имени в текстбоксе и смена фокуса с текстбокса не запускает сеттер для `SelectedClient`. Но даже если запустить сеттер иными способами, то ошибка валидации не воспринимается в представлении (красная рамках вокруг текстбокса). Я подозреваю что дело в том,что имя свойства `"SelectedParticipant.NameLong1"` записано некорректно, но не знаю правильного способа его записи.

Eсли я создаю отдельное свойство привязки для `NameLong1` и каждого другого свойства, то валидация работает нормально, но количество писанины при таком подходе резко возрастает.

**UPD**
Руководствуясь комментарием @Kotomi я во-первых заменил кастомный текстбокс на стандартный текстбокс для ясности, а во-вторых провел сравнительный тест 2х текстбоксов привязанных по-разному:

```
                    <!--Текстбокс привязанный через объект 
                    selectedClient. 
                    Предпочтительный мной вариант, но сеттер не 
                    вызывается при изменении значения, а интерфейс 
                    игнорирует ошибку-->
                    <TextBox 
                        Text="{Binding SelectedParticipant.NameLong1,
                        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    />
                    <!--Текстбокс, привязанный напрямую к отдельному 
                    свойству NameLong1. 
                    Работает как надо: текстбокс краснеет при превышении 
                    лимита символов и возвращается обратно при стирании 
                    строки-->
                    <TextBox 
                        Text="{Binding NameLong1,
                        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    />
```

Модель представления:

```
    private Participant selectedParticipant;
    public Participant SelectedParticipant
    {
        get { return selectedParticipant; }
        set
        {
            dataErrorVM.ClearErrors("SelectedParticipant.NameLong1");
            if (value.NameLong1.Length > 10)
                dataErrorVM.AddError("SelectedParticipant.NameLong1", "name is too long!!");
            selectedParticipant = value;
            if (isEditEnabled == true)
                IsEditEnabled = false;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedParticipant));
            OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityCompany");
            OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityPerson");
        }
    }

    public string NameLong1
    {
        get { return selectedParticipant.NameLong1; }
        set
        {
            dataErrorVM.ClearErrors("NameLong1");
            if (value.Length > 10)
            { dataErrorVM.AddError("NameLong1", "name is too long!!"); }    

            selectedParticipant.NameLong1 = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NameLong1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `...="{Binding ..., ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` Если так не будет работать, то вам предстоит показать ваш кастомный текстбокс

Comment: @Kotomi исправил текстбоксы на обычные и немного конкретизировал вопрос, добавив 2 сравнительные попытки решения.